# Why does Siddur Avodat Yisrael not contain piyutim for a wedding?

Tags: marriage, prayer-book, song-poetry

[Levush HaHur (*minhagim*)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14585&st=&pgnum=269) records what seems to have been the widespread *ashkenazi* practice to recite certain *piyutim* on the *shabbat* of a wedding. (I assume this means where the *chupah* takes place on a Friday and the wedding celebrations are held on *shabbat*.)

The famed and voluminous [*Siddur Avodat Yisrael*](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807) of [Seligman Baer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seligman_Baer), while containing *piyutim* for pretty much every conceivable occasion and special day, does not, as far as I can tell, contain these wedding *piyutim*. Why not?

Had the recitation of these wedding *piyutim* fallen out of practice by the mid-19th century? Or maybe Friday weddings were simply not held any more and therefore there was no practical purpose in printing them? Did Baer print or refer to these *piyutim* anywhere else?

Comment: Does it have milah?

Comment: @DoubleAA It sure does. p815 of the pdf on HebrewBooks

Comment: It can't be they gave up entirely since he prints this piyut for wedding https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42807&st=&pgnum=263 I'm still betting it's hiding in there somewhere

Comment: It's also there in the latest Safah Berurah (see in the older edition): https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19723&pgnum=156

Comment: Although it's missing from the new piyut book: https://moreshesashkenaz.org/mm/samples/ShirShevachTOC.pdf

Comment: BTW, when I spotted this piyut a while ago, I asked a few rabbonim, and they said that once the Jews could live outside the ghetto (i.e. 19th century), having a wedding on the Shabbat fell more and more out of fashion.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I see the Elokeichem for a wedding in Safah Berurah. Does it have the Yotzer?